# How to find out why a file has been deemed text or binary by git for EOL conversion?

Tags: git, line-endings, eol

If a `.gitattributes` is present in the repository or a configuration option is set to enable end-of-line (EOL) conversion, `git` needs to make a decision whether a file is `text` or `binary`.

Sometimes this decision is not obvious, e.g. if invisible characters are present in the file, see https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/file-detected-as-binary-not-displayed-as-text-in-bitbucket-892611499.html for an example.

The presence of characters which cause the file to recognized as something that it is not, is something that you might want to fix in most cases. However, the analysis with `hexdump` and `vi` as proposed in the linked post can be exhaustive and for some files and/or users practially impossible. Is there a way to find out what causes `git` to recognize a file as text or binary in a verbose matter (e.g. "reconized [path] as binary because of presence of [some codepoint] at line [n]")?

Our team is using Git 2.19 and 2.17 on Ubuntu 18.10, Windows 10 and macOS.

Answer (score 4):

`git` relies on `buffer_is_binary` in its [xdiff-interface.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/xdiff-interface.c) file to decide whether a file is binary or text. That function is called from Git's merging code, among other places. The logic is straightforward - a file is binary if there's a `0` byte in the first `8000` bytes of it. The code is:

```
#define FIRST_FEW_BYTES 8000
int buffer_is_binary(const char *ptr, unsigned long size)
{
    if (FIRST_FEW_BYTES < size)
        size = FIRST_FEW_BYTES;
    return !!memchr(ptr, 0, size);
}
```

As such, you can have very simple files being detected as binary if they're encoded in UTF-16, which is a common reason for Git treating files as binary. A text file containing

```
a b
```

will be detected as binary if saved in UTF-16 because its `hexdump` output is, with the LF file ending:

```
0000000 6100 2000 6200 0a00
```

For instance, the space (`0x20` in ASCII or UTF-8) is encoded as `0x0020` in UTF-16, hence Git considers the file binary.

So a "verbose" mode wouldn't really help much as you need to locate `0` bytes. `grep` could do that in Perl-regex mode such as `grep -obaUP "\x00" filename` to print byte offsets of `0`-value bytes.

Comment: Valuable input, thank you. Does the absence of a `0` byte within the first 8000 bytes mean that the text ought to be treated as text? My test case was a repository with `* text eol=lf` in `.gitattributes` in which git wants to change line feeds after `git rm --cached -r . && git add .` in a `.jar` and `.git` which both contain a `0` byte according to the presented `grep` test.

Comment: I think that `.gitattributes` would just override the detection. However, the `text` attribute is mostly for line-endings. It will still have binary behavior in several places, such as when diffing. You might want to set the `diff` attribute, e.g. `* diff`.

Answer (score 0):

`git ls-files --eol` displays information about how files are identified by git and how they're committed:

> --eol
>
> Show  and  of files.  is the file content identification used by Git when the "text" attribute is "auto" (or not set and core.autocrlf is not false).  is either "-text", "none", "lf", "crlf", "mixed" or "".
>
> "" means the file is not a regular file, it is not in the index or not accessible in the working tree.
>
> is the attribute that is used when checking out or committing, it is either "", "-text", "text", "text=auto", "text eol=lf", "text eol=crlf". Since Git 2.10 "text=auto eol=lf" and "text=auto eol=crlf" are supported.
>
> Both the  in the index ("i/") and in the working tree ("w/") are shown for regular files, followed by the ("attr/").

from the [`git ls-files` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)